# Combinatorial problem in a maze.

Tags: combinatorics, artificial-intelligence, searching

> We have a robot trapped in a maze of size $M \times N$ but we don't
>   know what is its position initially. We want the robot to exit the
>   maze but each time we move it we cannot be sure if it did move
>   effectively into the direction we told it to move or if it hit a wall
>   and remained in the same place it was.
>
> ¿What's the size of the space of states for this search problem?

I know the answer is $2^{MN}$ but I don't see how this is shown. The exit we are looking for is just a position of the maze.

Comment: Does "size of this search problem" mean the number of moves we need before we're guaranteed the robot escapes the maze? Also, if the robot exits the maze, are we notified of that immediately?

Comment: One more quesiton. Does "size $M \times N$" mean an $M$ by $N$ grid of either walls or non-walls?

Comment: The size of the state space and the number of moves before we're guaranteed the robot escapes the maze are very different. I think you have to pick one or the other. In order to understand the search problem here, I think it would help for you to say exactly what it is we are searching for. I don't think the problem is clear.

Comment: @6005 did that solve your question?

Comment: No, your question is still unclear. You didn't even define the state space or the search problem. But I am going to bed anyway.

Comment: I don't think you can move the robot out for sure

Comment: Actually you can, hm... really interesting, so you want to know maximal number of movements needed to get it out?